# How to send multiple values in a href link in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to send multiple values to a different page using a `href` link. But what I retrieve is the first 2 values only, rest shows an error of undefined index.

My code is:

```
<?php 

echo "<a href='index.php?choice=search&cat=".$cat."&subcat=".$subcat."&srch=".$srch."&page=".$next."'> Next </a>";

?>
```

I get the values of "choice" and "cat" only.
Please tell me whats wrong in the above code.

Comment: Try `htmlspecialchars(http_build_query(array('choice' => 'search', 'cat' => $cat, 'subcat' => $subcat, 'srch' => $srch, 'page' => $next)))` to generate a well-formed query string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using urlencode, as if there are any special characters in the strings, it could have an effect on the querystring as a whole;

```
echo "<a href='index.php?choice=search&cat=".urlencode($cat)."&subcat=".urlencode($subcat)."&srch=".urlencode($srch)."&page=".urlencode($next)."'> Next </a>";
```

Plus you had a space between srch and page, that could have been causing a problem.

Comment: Ampersands must be escaped too.

Comment: yes, good point! @Sahil, refer to knittl's answer for escaping the ampersands

Answer (score 3):

You must HTML-escape those ampersands properly:

```
?coice=search&amp;cat=...&amp;subcat=...&amp;srch=...
```

`&sub` (of `&subcat`) gets interpreted as `&sub;` which is a special HTML entity for the subset operator:

```
&sub; or &#8834; = subset of ⊂
```

Also make sure you properly escape your variables to prevent XSS.

Comment: @Sahil: It can. Browsers do their best (or worst) to try figure out what you could have meant. They often get it wrong.