# How to Send Multiple Variable in single header?

Tags: php, html, forms, header

I am using this code to send just one variable:

**Variable:**

1. Username

   `header("Location: ultrapro.php?username=".$_POST['username']);`

If I want to send more then one variable like:

1. Username
2. Password
3. Phone

---Code----------?

Comment: `?username=".$_POST['username']."&password=".$_POST['password']...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708112/how-to-send-mutiple-values-in-a-href-link-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **bad** idea to send your username and password through a `GET` request. Don't do it.

If you really must, then use `http_build_query()`:

```
$query = array(
    'username' => $_POST['username'], 
    'password' => $_POST['password'],
    'phone' => $_POST['phone']
    );

$query = http_build_query($query);
header("Location: ultrapro.php?$query");
```

Comment: Its just a option i have given

Comment: @RedSun: must have been due to the stray dot. I've removed it -- try again. Protip: instead of saying `not working`, you should try to find out why it's not working. Adding `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the very top of your script might help with debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `&` ..

```
header("Location: ultrapro.php?username=me&password=dontknow&phone=09090909");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&` to concatenate the parameters:

```
 header("Location: ultrapro.php?var1=".$_GET['var1']."&var2=".$_GET['var2']."&var3=".$_GET['var3']);
```

Comment: You could avoid wrong quotations by [properly formatting the code](http://phtml.org).. (remove `."` at the end)

Answer (score 0):

header("Location: " . $username . "?password=" . $pass . "&phone=" . $phone);

Comment: Please __stop__ putting spam links into your answers that have no connection to the answer. If you want to advertise your website, do that on your user profile. Thanks.